# Rename Excel sheets with Reporting Services 2008 R2

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have 2 tablix's. I have entered a page break after the first tablix so that the tables show up on two sheets. However, each sheet is named Sheet1 and Sheet2. How do I give it its own unique name automatically through the reporting services application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When exporting to Excel, you can set the first sheet name with the **Report** -> **InitialPageName** property:

[image]

Further sheets are triggered by page breaks, and in SSRS 2008R2 and above you can name sheets using the PageName property. This can be set in various locations where page breaks can be triggered, e.g. a Tablix:

[image]

Or a group within a tablix that has page breaks between group instances; here you might make it expression-based with a field in the report:

[image]

See [Worksheet Tab Names](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx#WorksheetTabNames) for more information.