# Naming sheets in SSRS when imported to Excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have put page breaks in my SSRS report. When report imported to Excel, report is divided into different sheets according to page breaks. Is it possible somehow name those sheets? Thanks for assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename excel sheets with Reporting Services 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142678/rename-excel-sheets-with-reporting-services-2008-r2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily change the tab name by setting the "Page Name" field on the properties sheet of the group (in this example "Buyer") that is providing the page break.
[image]

Comment: Seems like what I need. Thanks. But how can I Name each tab with different names?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with standard SSRS, but I know you can do it with OfficeWriter by SoftArtisans.

It's a proprietary application which isn't cheap, but it let's you create a template in Excel which you can then export the report into. You can do stuff like create charts and pivot tables as well which get populated automatically.

We have used their product and it works well. Their app can also be used to generate other Office artifacts such as Word docs.

(BTW I have no affiliation with SoftArtisans)

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I Name each tab with different names?

As Randy pointed out, the **PageName** is used to name tabs when a report is exported to Excel. Normally you would use a field name for the **PageName** expression.

If your page breaks are due to a Group, you would probably want to use the name of the group as the **PageName**. For instance, if you had a report of sales by **customer** with a separate tab for each customer, you would probably want to use the **customer name** field as the **PageName** expression.

> =Fields!Customer_Name.Value

Answer (score 0):

If you add the left(buyer,5) etc..into your dataset, put this as the initial group in your report then (page break between each instance of a group) and also use this field as the page name..should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the tablix properties. Type the "SheetName" you need under "PageName" expression. It is better to assign this property from a Global variable, but if you need a custom set name for each of your Excel tabs, this is the way.